# Download gae application issue, Can't create directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine

trying to download the source code from gae developer account.

```
appcfg.py download_app -A appname /"my folder"/path/appname
```

When I download the app, it gave me this error:

```
 2013-03-11 14:37:53,807 ERROR appcfg.py:1791 Couldn't create directory "/path-to-folder/admin": [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path-to-folder'
```

How to fix this problem?

Edited: Nevermind, I logged in to root and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the folder where you try to place the app, has the right permissions set.

Comment: i chmod 777 on that folder, but it doesn't help.